# How to say that numbers are not accurate

Tags: vocabulary

Let's say there is a graph showing that the prices on coffee are going to grow with *5,00%* anually. How can I specify that the growth might as well be *4,70%* or *5,10%*?

Comment: It would help to see a sample sentence. Do you mean something like "*The growth is ___ 5%*" or more like "*We ___ the growth numbers into integer percentages*"?

Answer (score 1):

> Let's say there is a graph showing that the prices on coffee are going to grow with 5,00% anually. How can I specify that the growth might as well be 4,70% or 5,10%?

It would help to know how you reached your figure of 5%.

If this is an *average* or *mean* figure then you could state:

> I expect the price of coffee to grow *an average* of 5% annually.

Or, if it isn't strictly a mathematical average, say for example it is a *median* figure (technically another kind of average, but perhaps not as widely understood) or you have *estimated* it based on some actual past growth figures, you could say:

> I *estimate* that the price of coffee will grow 5% annually.

Another way of expressing this:

> The price of coffee is expected to grow an estimated 5% annually.

Estimates are more likely to require some qualification; that is you might want to give some hint at how you reached that estimate so that people trust it. You could say:

> Based on growth in previous years it is estimated that the price of coffee will continue to grow 5% annually.

Another useful word is *approximation*. This means a value is *nearly* but *not exactly* correct.

You might say:

> The price of coffee is expected to grow *approximately* 5% annually.

Comment: Very minor criticism of a good answer. "Approximately" has more than one meaning. Informally, it does not preclude exactness. Saying that someone has an annual income of "approximately one hundred thousand" does not imply a certainty that the person does not have that exact income. It implies a lack of knowledge about the exact figure. And I like your points about estimates; wish I had mentioned them in my answer.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Interesting point, but by the same token an *estimate* can turn out to be correct. Saying something is an estimate, or an average does not mean it will not turn out to be the *actual* value. The word is used to describe how you *reached* that figure.

Comment: Astralbee I fully agree that an estimate may be exact. I did not mean to imply otherwise. My point is that the errors in many approximations may be exactly bounded 0 < |pi - 3.14| < 0.01. Estimates frequently are not so bounded. That is why your point that disclosure of the basis of estimatation is useful is such a good point.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways.

About 5%. Informal.

Around 5%. Informal.

Approximately 5%. Informal.

You must be careful with "approximate." It sometimes means "close to but not equal." For example, someone may say pi is approximately equal to 3.1416 to indicate, among other things, that pi is not exactly 3.1416.

Scientists and mathematicians have formal conventions about how to indicate the degree of accuracy in a reported number.